# Suppress warnings in ParallelTable

Tags: parallelization, warning-messages, list-manipulation

I'm using `ParallelTable` to evaluate a function that involves `NIntegrate`. There are a lot of `NIntegrate::slwcon` warning messages. In fact, every kernel prints the same messages.

I am aware that Mathematica is printing these warnings and now want to suppress them. I tried `Quiet[]` and `Off[NIntegrate::slwcon`. But they seem to have no effect whatsoever when using `ParallelTable`.

How can I turn off (any) warning message when using `ParallelTable`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Not knowing quite what you're doing this may or may not help.  I think the problem is you're turning the warnings off in the master kernel and the warnings you're seeing come from the slaves. I'd suggest...

```
ParallelTable[Quiet[your code here],{your iterator here}];
```

OR

```
ParallelEvaluate[Off[NIntegrate::slwcon]]; ParallelTable[your code here, {your iterator here}]
```

Comment: Actually instead of the second option you can just do `ParallelTable[Off[NIntegrate::slwcon];your code here,{your iterator here}];`. The `Off[]` call shouldn't take much time, so I think it's safe enough to execute it for each iteration.