# Customize how many of the same warning messages are printed from parallel kernels?

Tags: warning-messages, parallelization, customization

I have an evaluation inside a `ParallelTable` which sometimes gives me warning messages. After a certain amount of warning messages it will say:

```
 General::stop :  "Further output of "General::munfl", "MessageName" will be suppressed during this calculation
```

Unfortunately, this message number limit seems to apply for each parallel kernel separately.

Now, since I calculate on a lot of parallel kernels and the specific message I get is kind of long, I get 10 pages worth of warnings (if I were to print them), so I was wondering whether there is some setting where I can customize how many error messages I want before the General::stop message.

I don't want to completely disable these warnings, which is the only advice I found so far, as it is helpful to know some warnings occured, but as it is now it is very cumbersome to delete all the messages manually each time.

If there is a way to have one kernel print the messages, and mute the others, that would also be a possible solution (At least in my use case, because if one kernel produces error messages, they all do, but this way of solving it might be less useful to other users who search for this problem). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You could redirect your messages to a file instead of the front end - http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Messages.html - that way you can still view them but the front end won't become cluttered.

Comment: I don't have time to dig in, but a thought: `Quiet[Check[{0^0, 0^0},"ERROR",Power::indet]]` suppresses the message, but returns "ERROR" since `Check` is inside `Quiet` - this might be a way to generate one message for the whole calculation.

Comment: With the menu `Mathematica | Preferences ... | Advanced | Open Option Inspector | Global Preferences | Global Options | Message Options | "MaxMessageCount"` set value to `1` or whatever value you desire.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58074/280

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us `Trace` how messages from parallel kernels are handled in the main kernel:

```
Flatten[Trace[ParallelTable[Message[General::munfl, $KernelID], {1}], 
    LinkRead | MessagePacket | TextPacket] /. 
   seq : {_HoldForm, _} :> Rule @@ seq] // Column
```

[image: screenshot]

We see that the subkernel first returns `MessagePacket[General, "munfl"]` which isn't printed, then it returns

```
TextPacket["General::munfl: 4 is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost."]
```

which is passed to `` Parallel`Protected`PacketHandler `` along with the corresponding `KernelObject`, from which it extracts the `$KernelID` and passes it as a part of `CellLabel` to `CellPrint`. This is how the original message from the subkernel appears in the evaluation Notebook.

Hence we can intercept the message printing by overloading either `` Parallel`Protected`PacketHandler `` or `CellPrint`. I tried to work with the first without success, but overloading of `CellPrint` works:

```
Unprotect[CellPrint];
CellPrint[Cell[s_String, "Print", CellLabel -> label_String, ShowCellLabel -> True]] := 
  Block[{$inCP = True, 
     mname = First[StringCases[s, RegularExpression["^(\\w+::\\w+):"] :> "$1", 1], False]},
     If[! AssociationQ[$SubkernelMessages], $SubkernelMessages = <||>];
     If[! NumericQ[$SubkernelMessagesLimit], $SubkernelMessagesLimit = 3];
     If[KeyExistsQ[$SubkernelMessages, mname], 
       ++$SubkernelMessages[mname], $SubkernelMessages[mname] = 1];
     If[$SubkernelMessages[mname] <= $SubkernelMessagesLimit, 
      CellPrint[Cell[s, "Print", CellLabel -> label, ShowCellLabel -> True]]]; /; 
     StringQ[mname]] /; 
   Not[TrueQ[$inCP]] && StringMatchQ[label, RegularExpression["\\(kernel \\d+\\)"]];
Protect[CellPrint];
```

After evaluating the above we can use `ParallelTable` as follows:

```
$SubkernelMessages =.;
$SubkernelMessagesLimit = 2;
ParallelTable[Message[General::munfl, $KernelID], {100}];
```

[image: screenshot]

Note that `$SubkernelMessages` is kept during the whole main kernel session, not per evaluation as `$MessageList`. Hence it should be purged manually before every *input* where you call a `Parallel*` function (as I do in the above example) if you wish to mimic the default behavior of `Message`. However, it is not difficult to automate this too:

```
Unprotect[CellPrint];
CellPrint[Cell[s_String, "Print", CellLabel -> label_String, ShowCellLabel -> True]] := 
  Block[{$inCP = True, 
     mname = First[StringCases[s, RegularExpression["^(\\w+::\\w+):"] :> "$1", 1], False]},
     If[Not[AssociationQ[$SubkernelMessages]] || $SubkernelMessages["$Line"] =!= $Line, 
       $SubkernelMessages = <|"$Line" -> $Line|>];
     If[! NumericQ[$SubkernelMessagesLimit], $SubkernelMessagesLimit = 3];
     If[KeyExistsQ[$SubkernelMessages, mname], 
       ++$SubkernelMessages[mname], $SubkernelMessages[mname] = 1];
     If[$SubkernelMessages[mname] <= $SubkernelMessagesLimit, 
      CellPrint[Cell[s, "Print", CellLabel -> label, ShowCellLabel -> True]]]; /; 
     StringQ[mname]] /; 
   Not[TrueQ[$inCP]] && StringMatchQ[label, RegularExpression["\\(kernel \\d+\\)"]];
Protect[CellPrint];
```

With this definition `$SubkernelMessagesLimit` will limit the number of printed messages from the subkernels for every input `$Line` of the main kernel:

```
$SubkernelMessagesLimit = 1;
ParallelTable[Message[General::munfl, $KernelID]; $KernelID, {20}]
ParallelTable[Message[General::munfl, $KernelID]; $KernelID, {20}]
```

[image: screenshot]

---

As a bonus. If you evaluate ([related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131856/280))

```
ParallelEvaluate[SetOptions[$Output, PageWidth -> Infinity]];
```

then the messages from the parallel kernels will be printed without the compulsory linebreaks:

```
$SubkernelMessages =.;
ParallelTable[Message[General::munfl, $KernelID], {100}];
```

[image: screenshot]

Additionally, you can get a nicer appearance with automating word-wrapping if you change the inner `CellPrint` part of the above custom definitions to the following:

```
CellPrint[Cell[BoxData@s, "Message", CellLabel -> label, ShowCellLabel -> True]]
```

Here is the result:

[image: screenshot]

Also, you can get the statistics of the `Message`s generated in the subkernels:

```
$SubkernelMessages
```

> ```
> <|"General::munfl" -> 36, "General::stop" -> 12|>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

> If there is a way to have one kernel print the messages, and mute the others, that would also be a possible solution (At least in my use case, because if one kernel produces error messages, they all do, but this way of solving it might be less useful to other users who search for this problem). Is there a way to do that?

Yes, just evaluate `Off[General::munfl];` in all parallel kernels excepting one:

```
LaunchKernels[]

ParallelEvaluate[Off[General::munfl], Rest@Kernels[]]

ParallelTable[Message[General::munfl, $KernelID], {100}];
```

[image: screenshot]

---

> The suggestion to redirect `$Messages` unfortunately only redirected output from the main kernel, not from the parallel kernels, which is my main problem here.

You need to redefine `$Messages` in the parallel kernels, not in the main kernel:

```
ParallelEvaluate[$Messages = {OpenAppend["Messages.txt", PageWidth -> Infinity]}]
```

> ```
> {{OutputStream["Messages.txt", 3]}, {OutputStream["Messages.txt", 3]}, {OutputStream["Messages.txt", 3]}, {OutputStream["Messages.txt", 3]}}
> ```

Now all the messages from the parallel kernels will be appended to the file "Messages.txt":

```
ParallelTable[Message[General::munfl, $KernelID], {100}];

Import["Messages.txt"]
```

[image: screenshot]

---

> The suggestion from Bob Hanlon in the comments
>
> > With the menu Mathematica | Preferences ... | Advanced | Open Option
> > Inspector | Global Preferences | Global Options | Message Options |
> > "MaxMessageCount" set value to 1
>
> still yielded too much output in my case, but may be the better option
> for others.

Actually the undocumented `"MaxMessageCount"` FrontEnd option [doesn't affect this behavior at all](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58430/280). Moreover, by default you can't rely on the  [`General::stop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/General/stop.html) when working with subkernels, because `General::stop` limits the number of messages only for single *input* (single evaluation), while the `Parallel*` machinery can break the computation into several evaluations per subkernel:

```
ParallelTable[$KernelID, {20}]
```

> ```
> {4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1}
> ```

You can affect this behavior via `Method` suboptions though:

```
ParallelTable[$KernelID, {20}, Method -> "EvaluationsPerKernel" -> 1]
```

> ```
> {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
> ```

You can overcome this problem without changing the `Method` suboptions by overloading `Message` *in the subkernels* using the technique from [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Mar/msg00139.html) MathGroup post:

```
ParallelEvaluate[
  $globalMessageList = {};
  Unprotect[Message];
  Message[args___] := 
   Block[{$inMsg = True, $MessageList = $globalMessageList}, Message[args];
     $globalMessageList = $MessageList;] /; ! TrueQ[$inMsg];
  Protect[Message];
  ];
```

Or better you can use methods from [another](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262718/280) answer of mine here.

Answer (score 0):

As no one seems interested in answering (in an actual answer), I'll report what I did.

From another [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37322/42688), I got this tip:

```
ParallelTable[Off[General::munfl];your code here,{your iterator here}]
```

This turns off all messages unfortunately, but it's the best thing I found in my case.

The suggestion from Bob Hanlon in the comments

> With the menu Mathematica | Preferences ... | Advanced | Open Option Inspector | Global Preferences | Global Options | Message Options | "MaxMessageCount" set value to 1

still yielded too much output in my case, but may be the better option for others.

The suggestion to redirect $Messages unfortunately only redirected output from the main kernel, not from the parallel kernels, which is my main problem here.

Comment: A few days ago I did something like what you seek [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/237162/4999), but not in a parallelized evaluation.  See the first code block that ends with `Tally[Flatten@messages]`.