# Is there a reason behind strange noise appearing for some coefficients of polynomial in NIntegrate?

Tags: numerical-integration

It occurs for instance here:

```
b = -1; c = 1; d = -1;
Plot[NIntegrate[1/(a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c*x + d), {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 2}]
```

but not with these values:

```
  b = 1; c = 1; d = 1;
```

The phenomenon seems to appear with negative coefficients.

Comment: If you use `RootSum[]` instead, things are much nicer: `With[{b = -1, c = 1, d = -1}, Plot[RootSum[d + c #1 + b #1^2 + a #1^3 &, (Log[10 - #1] - Log[-#1])/(c + 2 b #1 + 3 a #1^2) &], {a, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]]`

Comment: Your integrand has a pole in the integration interval. This makes the numeric  integral error prone. For the second set of parameters, the poles are outside the integration interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generation ago `Plot` used to let all (or many) messages escape, so that if you plotted a function like `1/x`, you wouldn't be surprised at a divide-by-zero error message. You got used to typing `Plot[1/x, {x, -1, 1}] // Quiet`. Nowadays, `Plot` is very aggressive at suppressing message, too aggressive in this case, imo.

Modifying [@Szabolcs's code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20371/4999), here's a way to see that `Plot` is hiding thousands of nonconvergence `NIntegrate::ncvb` errors from you:

```
b = -1; c = 1; d = -1;
messages = {};
clearMessages[] := messages = {};
collectMessages[m_] := 
  messages = {messages, m /. Hold[_[mm_, ___], _] :> HoldForm[mm]};
Internal`HandlerBlock[
  {"Message", collectMessages},
  Plot[NIntegrate[1/(a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c*x + d), {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 2}]
  ];
Tally[Flatten@messages]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here's another way I might do it, since I can never remember the handler stuff:

```
obj[a_?NumericQ] := Module[{res},
   Check[
    res = NIntegrate[1/(a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c*x + d), {x, 0, 10}],
    ++foo; res,
    NIntegrate::ncvb]
   ];
foo = 0;
Plot[obj[a], {a, 0, 2}]
foo
(*  plot omitted *)
(*  2986  *)
```

I ignore the slow convergence `NIntegrate::slwcon` warnings, which are hints why the integral does not converge.  But I already know why it does not converge.

P.S. There is a method option `"SuppressMessages"`, but it is undocumented and seems not to apply. It takes `True` or `False` for values, but it makes no difference here:

```
Plot[NIntegrate[1/(a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c*x + d), {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 2},
 MaxRecursion -> 0, (* for speed *)
 Method -> {"SuppressMessages" -> False}]
```

Try it with `Method -> {"SuppressMessages" -> None}` and you will be told to use `True` or `False`.  So it is an option that is checked.