# Highly oscillatory region in plot

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I am new to Mathematica and this forum so apologies in advance if I am not doing anything properly (do let me know). I am trying to visualize the imaginary part of an integral of `q` w.r.t `r` when plotted against `w` in the code bellow. `t1` and `t2` are the limits of integration and are functions of `l` and `w`. The plot looks weird for `w < 0.5` (blue patch on the left). What does it mean when this kind of behavior is in the plot? Is this due to the nature of my integrand or is there something I can do to fix it? Ideally for `w < 0.5` it should be a curve/line instead of this dark patch. Any help is appreciated.

My code:

```
q[r_, l_, w_] := 
  Sqrt[(-l (1 + l) (-(2/r^3) + 1/r^2) + 1/r^4 + w^2)/(1 - 2/r)^2 - 1/(4(-2 + r)^2)];

t1[l_, w_] := 
  1/24 (2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[(192 w^2 + (49 + (-117649 + 525888 w^2 + 24 Sqrt[3]Sqrt[-73530625 w^2 + 159891584 w^4 - 4096 w^6])^(1/3))^2)/(w^2 (-117649 + 525888 w^2 + 24 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[-73530625 w^2 + 159891584 w^4 - 4096 w^6])^(1/3))] + Sqrt[6] \[Sqrt](1/w^2 (392 + (-4802-384 w^2)/(-117649 + 525888 w^2 +24 Sqrt[3]Sqrt[-73530625 w^2 + 159891584 w^4 - 4096 w^6])^(1/3) - 2 (-117649 + 525888 w^2 + 24 Sqrt[3]Sqrt[-73530625 w^2 + 159891584 w^4 - 4096 w^6])^(1/3) - (2304 Sqrt[3])/Sqrt[(192 w^2 + (49 + (-117649 + 525888 w^2 + 24 Sqrt[3]Sqrt[-73530625 w^2 + 159891584 w^4 - 4096 w^6])^(1/3))^2)/(w^2 (-117649 + 525888w^2 + 24 Sqrt[3]Sqrt[-73530625 w^2 + 159891584 w^4 - 4096 w^6])^(1/3))])));

t2[l_, w_] := 
  1/(4 Sqrt[3]) (Sqrt[(192 w^2 + (49 + (-117649 + 525888 w^2 + 24 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[-73530625 w^2 + 159891584 w^4 - 4096 w^6])^(1/3))^2)/(w^2 (-117649 + 525888 w^2 + 24 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[-73530625 w^2 + 159891584 w^4 - 4096 w^6])^(1/3))] - 1/Sqrt[2] (\[Sqrt](1/w^2 (392 + (-4802 - 384 w^2)/(-117649 + 525888 w^2 + 24 Sqrt[3]Sqrt[-73530625 w^2 + 159891584 w^4 - 4096 w^6])^(1/3) - 2 (-117649 + 525888 w^2 + 24 Sqrt[3]Sqrt[-73530625 w^2 + 159891584 w^4 - 4096 w^6])^(1/3) - (2304 Sqrt[3])/Sqrt[(192 w^2 + (49 + (-117649 + 525888 w^2 + 24 Sqrt[3]Sqrt[-73530625 w^2 + 159891584 w^4 - 4096 w^6])^(1/3))^2)/(w^2 (-117649 + 525888 w^2 + 24 Sqrt[3]Sqrt[-73530625 w^2 + 159891584 w^4 - 4096 w^6])^(1/3))]))));

l = 2;

Plot[
  γ = NIntegrate[q[r, l, w], {r, t2[l, w], t1[l, w]}]; Im[γ], {w, 0.01, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Neither the definition of `t1` nor t2` shows `l` on its righthand side, so those functions are not functions of `l` and `w`, but only of `w`. Good practice would be to remove `l` from the lefthand side of the definitions as well.

Comment: I get an error from `NIntegrate` when I run your code, don't you?  Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237154/is-there-a-reason-behind-strange-noise-appearing-for-some-coefficients-of-polyno/237162#237162

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small round-off errors in `t2[l, w]` and `t1[l, w]` lead them to have small imaginary parts, randomly changing as `w` changes. `NIntegrate` will integrate between them along a line in the complex plane.  In turn, the small, random imaginary parts are propagated through the evaluation of `q[r, l, w] = Sqrt[...]`.  For certain values of `r` the argument of the square-root should be a negative real number, but it actually carries a small, random imaginary part — in particular, the imaginary part has a random sign (as `w` changes).  Consequently, the argument of `Sqrt[...]` dances back and forth across the branch cut, causing the imaginary part of `q[r, l, w]` to discontinuously change signs for certain values of `r` as `w` changes.

My recommendation is to get rid of the imaginary parts with either of the following (first one seems better):

```
Plot[Im@NIntegrate[q[r, l, w], {r, Chop@t2[l, w], Chop@t1[l, w]}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 4], {w, 0.01, 2}]

Plot[Im@NIntegrate[q[r, l, w], {r, Re@t2[l, w], Re@t1[l, w]}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 20], {w, 0.01, 2}]
```

`MaxRecursion -> 20` gets rid of an error message but yields an unimportant warning. Using `PrecisionGoal -> 4` instead of `MaxRecursion` eliminates all messages and warnings*, is a reasonable lower goal for plotting, and speeds things up a little.

*Note: The error/warning message we get is the result of `Plot` testing its argument near the beginning of the plot domain (i.e. `w` near `0.01`). After that, `Plot` routinely suppresses many error messages, which hides from the user problems that may exist.  This issue came up recently here: [Is there a reason behind strange noise appearing for some coefficients of polynomial in NIntegrate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237154/is-there-a-reason-behind-strange-noise-appearing-for-some-coefficients-of-polyno/237162#237162)

Another approach to deal with round-off error is to use arbitrary-precision numbers, which @ciao shows.

Comment: Thanks for posting this -- I was too lazy today, to frame my comments into a proper answer.