# Wolframscript: Removing prepended message from Print in slave kernel

Tags: output-formatting, scripting, streams

I am running a parallelized algorithm using WolframScript and inside the function being passed to the various kernels, I have print statements that track the computation and output the print statements to the terminal. However, whenever a print statement is executed in the slave kernels, its prepended by

```
From KernelObject[<n>, Local kernel]:
```

where `<n>` is the `$KernelID`. So for example, a full print statement would return

```
From KernelObject[6, Local kernel]:
<my print statement>
```

where in the code, I have `Print[<my print statement>]`. However, with the number of kernels I have up and running, these prepended messages take up a lot of screen real estate. Is it possible to turn off these `From KernelObject...` messages so that I just have the original `Print` statement printed to screen? I am pretty new to Wolframscript so I haven't been able to determine a potential solution myself. Perhaps printing to an output stream?

A minimal working example would be for example

```
wolframscript -code 'ParallelEvaluate[Print["Hello"]]'
```

to be executed in the terminal. In my specific case, all the code is in a Wolfram Language Script file, so I am executing `wolframscript -file <myfile>`. But the results are identical, the print messages are prepended by the above message.

Thanks

EDIT:

Ok, I've managed to implement this in the standard front end by using `Trace[ParallelEvaluate[Print["Test"]], CellPrint]`, which shows me the exact pattern to overload in the Downvalues of CellPrint. So I simply set

```
CellPrint[Cell[s_, "Print", label_, ShowCellLabel -> True]] := 
  Block[{},
   CellPrint[Cell[s, "Print", ShowCellLabel -> False]]];
```

which is a bit brute force, but it works. However, this doesnt solve my problem. This only works in the FrontEnd, and not when using Wolframscript. Running `Trace[ParallelEvaluate[Print["Test"]], Print]` in a Terminal using

```shell
wolframscript -c 'Trace[ParallelEvaluate[Print["Test"]], Print]'
```

Shows me

```
{HoldForm[Print[From KernelObject[1, Local kernel]:]], HoldForm[Null], HoldForm[Print[d
]], HoldForm[Null]}
```

so it looks like wolframscript is inserting the values I want to print into a list of other strings that get printed along with it.
I'm not sure how to proceed from this point.

Comment: You can try to apply the approach described in this answer: "[Customize how many of the same warning messages are printed from parallel kernels?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262718/280)"

Comment: Thanks for the link. Messing with the backend like this is a whole new territory for me. I tried implementing your solution through that link, but I was unsuccessful. I tried removing the ShowCellLabel and CellLabel options (and tried analyzing with ```Trace```). I noticed, after running ```Unprotect[CellPrint]``` that CellPrint has other downvalues that are pretty obscure. If i remove all of them, then ```ParallelEvaluate[Print["Test"]]``` evaluates to nothing, theres no print statement, even with the custom definition as the only downvalue.

Comment: Perhaps [`$Post`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Post.html) can be used? For example, set `$Post=If[Head[#]===String,ToUpperCase[#],#]&` and then type `"Hello"`. This will not work for `Print` results, but perhaps one can adapt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to switch off printing of the `"From remote kernel:"` lines. The basic idea is to redefine `Print` for them:

```
Unprotect[Print]; 
Print["From remote kernel:"] = Null;
Protect[Print];
```

I've put it in a "test.m" file as follows:

```
Unprotect[Print]; 
Print["From remote kernel:"] = Null;
Protect[Print]; 
ParallelEvaluate[Print["Hello"]]
```

Here is how it is executed in the command prompt:

[image: screenshot]

P.S. It seems in your case something other is being printed. Hence you can try the following instead:

```
Unprotect[Print];
Print[expr_] /; ! FreeQ[expr, _KernelObject] = Null;
Print[expr_] /; ! FreeQ[expr, s_String /; StringContainsQ[s, "KernelObject"]] = Null;
Protect[Print];
```

Comment: This solves my problem, thanks for the solution. I combined all three down value definitions in my WL script and I now get the desired result.